# How to sum cells that don't contain a specific value

Tags: excel, vba, sum

I am trying count rows in Excel from the first sheet if they are different from the rows on the second sheet.

But there is something wrong.

`inicijaliDT` is a range with data I check on `Sheet2`.

```
inicijali = wsNOSTROSheet.Range("R" & brojac).Value
For Each Row In inicijaliDT
    If inicijali <> Row.Value Then
        brojRedaka = brojRedaka + 1
    'Else
        'Exit For
    End If
    Exit For
Next Row
```

Comment: Not very clear what you need accomplishing... Are there the same number of rows in each sheet? Do you want comparing rows 1 of the first sheet with row 1 of the second and so on? And count the rows which are not identic?

Comment: (1) You're exiting the loop after the first iteration.

Comment: (2) Is the range `inicijaliDt` a single column range? (3) You should think about the names you give your variables (e.g. `Row` is not a good name for a cell).

Answer (score 1):

If I correctly understood which you want accomplishing, please try the next code:

```
Sub testCompareRows()
 Dim sh1 As Worksheet, sh2 As Worksheet, lastR As Long, i As Long, cnt As Long
 
 Set sh1 = ActiveSheet 'use here your first sheet
 Set sh2 = sh1.Next    'use here your second sheet
 lastR = sh1.UsedRange.rows.count + sh1.UsedRange.row - 1
 For i = 1 To lastR
    With Application
        If Join(.Transpose(.Transpose(sh1.rows(i)))) <> _
            Join(.Transpose(.Transpose(sh2.rows(i)))) Then cnt = cnt + 1
    End With
 Next i
 If cnt > 0 Then MsgBox "There are " & cnt & " different rows..."
End Sub
```

You did not ask the clarification questions and the code assumes that both sheets have the same number of rows, each row number in a first sheet to be compared with the same row number of the second one...

Answer (score 1):

### Count Not Equal

If `inicijaliDT` is a **one-column** range, you can do one of the following:

```
Sub testLoop()
    Dim cel As Range
    Dim brojRedaka As Long
    inicijali = wsNOSTROSheet.Range("R" & brojac).Value
    For Each cel In inicijaliDT.Cells
        If cel.Value <> inicijali Then
            brojRedaka = brojRedaka + 1
        End If
    Next cel
    'Debug.Print brojRedaka
End Sub

Sub testCountIf()
    Dim brojRedaka As Long
    inicijali = wsNOSTROSheet.Range("R" & brojac).Value
    brojRedaka = inicijaliDT.Rows.Count _
        - Application.CountIf(inicijaliDT, inicijali)
    'Debug.Print brojRedaka
End Sub
```

If `inicijaliDT` is a **multi-column** range and you are trying to count the number of rows where `inicijali` is not found in any of their cells, you can do one of the following:

```
Sub testRowLoop()
    Dim RowRange As Range
    Dim cel As Range
    Dim brojRedaka As Long
    Dim isFound As Boolean
    inicijali = wsNOSTROSheet.Range("R" & brojac).Value
    For Each RowRange In inicijaliDT.Rows
        For Each cel In RowRange.Cells
            If cel.Value = inicijali Then
                isFound = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next cel
        If isFound Then
            isFound = False
        Else
            brojRedaka = brojRedaka + 1
        End If
    Next RowRange
    'Debug.Print brojRedaka
End Sub

Sub testRowMatch()
    Dim RowRange As Range
    Dim brojRedaka As Long
    inicijali = wsNOSTROSheet.Range("R" & brojac).Value
    For Each RowRange In inicijaliDT.Rows
        If IsError(Application.Match(inicijali, RowRange, 0)) Then
            brojRedaka = brojRedaka + 1
        End If
    Next RowRange
    ' Debug.Print brojRedaka
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This one you can customize. Remember to config the values in the code before you run it.

```
'TASK: count rows in first sheet that 
'have a different value to the same cells in the second sheet.

Sub countRows()

Dim positioner As Long, count As Long, last_row As Long
Dim db_first_row As Byte, col_n As Byte, name_s1 As String
Dim name_s2 As String, display_ans As String, msg As String
Dim display_in_cell As Boolean, display_in_msgbox As Boolean

'CONFIR HERE BEFORE YOU RUN IT
'------------------------------------------------
name_s1 = "Sheet1"         'name of first sheet
name_s2 = "Sheet2"         'name of second sheet
db_first_row = 2           'first row of the data set
col_n = 2                  'colum number of the data set
count = 0                  'from what number would you like to start counting?
display_in_cell = True     'do you want to display the answer in a specific cell?
display_ans = "C3"         'in what cell?
display_in_msgbox = True   'do you want to display the answer in a msgbox?
msg = "Different values counted: " 'message to display in msgbox
'------------------------------------------------

'get the last row of the data set
last_row = Sheets(name_s1).Cells(Rows.count, col_n).End(xlUp).Row

For positioner = db_first_row To last_row
    
    'if values of both sheets match in the same cell then count
    If Sheets(name_s1).Cells(positioner, col_n) <> _
    Sheets(name_s2).Cells(positioner, col_n) Then
            count = count + 1
        End If

Next positioner

If display_in_cell Then
    Sheets(name_s1).Range(display_ans) = count
End If

If display_in_msgbox Then
    MsgBox msg & count
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you I did not see that.

Comment: A few gentle comments: 1- You should always declare the type of each variable in a `Dim` statement, otherwise, all your variables will be of type `Variant` except the last on each line. 2- Whenever you're tempted to use `Integer` or `Byte` you should use `Long`. 3- In your `If` conditions you do not need the `= True` part if the variable is of type `Boolean`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. They are very helpful. Just one question, why would I use a Long variable for a number probably not bigger than 10, as the db_first_row?

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26409117/why-use-integer-instead-of-long/26409520#26409520) to *Why Use Integer Instead of Long?*.

Comment: @VBasic2008 the link provided is worth reading, thanks.